# Regex date validation yyyy-mm-dd returns null Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jira-rest-api, forge, jira-forge

I'm testing out my regex validator using js, I've tested the regex in tester it is valid but I think the problem is with my code, I'm fairly new to JS. Hoping someone can help me on this one. Thank you

So this is the input string that I use, then I tokenize the returned value to each string it's a valid yyyy-mm-dd format to check if it's a date.

```
project = "HRT: Human Resource Ticketing" AND (("Time to first response" = breached() OR "Time to resolution" = breached()) AND resolution = Done AND "Request Type" = "Payroll Dispute (HR)") AND (createdDate >= 2022-10-1 AND createdDate  <= 2022-10-31)
```

```
const items = token.split(" ");
    for (const item of items) {
    console.log(item.match("([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))"))
}
```

I don't know why it returns null, BTW I just need to capture the date so I can replace the date with whatever I want. Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you using `Intl` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the string `""` to a regex expression `//`. Instead of `"([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))"`, change it to this: `/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/`.

It should, for example, return the following array:

```
[
  '2022-10-31',
  '2022-10-31',
  '10',
  '31',
  index: 0,
  input: '2022-10-31)',
  groups: undefined
]
```

Where you can access the matched value by `item[0]`.

So the new code is as follows:

```
const token = `HRT: Human Resource Ticketing" AND (("Time to first response" = breached() OR "Time to resolution" = breached()) AND resolution = Done AND "Request Type" = "Payroll Dispute (HR)") AND (createdDate >= 2022-10-1 AND createdDate  <= 2022-10-31)`
const regex = /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/

const items = token.split(" ");
    for (const item of items) {
    const match = item.match(regex)
    if (match) console.log(match[0])
}
```

Comment: one thing there are two occurrences of yyyy-mm-dd `(2022-10-1 and 2022-10-31)` upon checking it only captures the first one, how do I get the second date?

Comment: Hello back. Your regex expression doesn't match if there is a single digit after `-`. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Try this: `([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-9]([0-9])?|[12]\d|3[01]))`.

Comment: hi here's the output: `INFO    01:10:40.845  805a800f2a757df6  DATE: 2022-09-01,2022-09-01,09,01,1` is there a way to get `2022-09-30`?

Comment: I need more information about how the output is produced, what do you mean by that? The regular expression now works with `2022-10-1`, but if you need something else, you can make the regular expression you want with the following tutorial: https://javascript.info/regular-expressions.

Comment: Need to capture all occurrences of yyyy-mm-dd the string. thank you